# NGINX: How to encapsulate common header settings to a function

Tags: nginx

My Nginx configuration looks like this:

```
location = /1 {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_http_version     1.1;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header       Connection "";
    proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
    proxy_set_header       Host $bucket;
    proxy_set_header       X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header       X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
    proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
    proxy_hide_header      x-amz-meta-server-side-encryption;
    proxy_hide_header      x-amz-server-side-encryption;
    proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
    proxy_ignore_headers   Set-Cookie;
    add_header             Cache-Control max-age=31536000;
    proxy_pass https://$bucket/1;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
  }

  location = /0 {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_http_version     1.1;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header       Connection "";
    proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
    proxy_set_header       Host $bucket;
    proxy_set_header       X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header       X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
    proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
    proxy_hide_header      x-amz-meta-server-side-encryption;
    proxy_hide_header      x-amz-server-side-encryption;
    proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
    proxy_ignore_headers   Set-Cookie;
    add_header             Cache-Control max-age=31536000;
    proxy_pass https://$bucket/0;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
  }
  }
```

And I have many `location` paths, and I need add the header settings to each of these paths, duplicating a lot of code.

Is there anyway I can add these to a function call? Something like:

```
set_s3_headers()
{
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_http_version     1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header       Connection "";
        proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
        proxy_set_header       Host $bucket;
        proxy_set_header       X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header       X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-meta-server-side-encryption;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-server-side-encryption;
        proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
        proxy_ignore_headers   Set-Cookie;
        add_header             Cache-Control max-age=31536000;
    }
```

And then do like:

```
location = /1 {
        set_s3_headers();
        proxy_pass https://$bucket/1;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
      }
    
      location = /0 {
        set_s3_headers();
        proxy_pass https://$bucket/0;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
      }
      }
```

Is this possible in nginx configuration?
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is "No". Nginx configuration isn't a programming language in any way (well, maybe except the directives from the rewrite module), it is a declarative configuration, and **DRY** principles isn't applicable here. You can make a separate file, e.g. `/etc/nginx/s3_proxy_params`, to specify all the common settings and include it under every needed location:

```
location = /0 {
    include s3_proxy_params;
    proxy_pass https://$bucket/0;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
}
...
```

However if you do not change your request URI (`/0` -> `/0`, `/1` -> `/1`, etc.), you are not obligated to specify that request URI with the `proxy_pass` directive, and instead of several locations like those you've shown in your question you can use something like

```
location ~ ^/(0|1)$ {
    ... proxy settings
    proxy_pass https://$bucket;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
}
```